# Using 1 function to make one value equal several different variables

Tags: javascript, function

I found a function that converts number values to number values with commas to easily display large numbers to the webpage viewer.  Unfortunately, the code I found online only successfully makes ONE variable equal to any value.  Due to the large number of variables I have to convert, it would be unpractical to make several different functions to accomplish this.  I need help modifying the function so it can take a value and its corresponding variable for storing it after it receives its comma.

Original Code:

```
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    //Whatever sole variable you want 
    = val;
}
```

My attempted (failed version) of the function:

```
//define variables that need to be comma-ed.
var a = 234858912795;
var b = 148582954;
var c = 59928104585125612324;
//Array of variables to be comma-ed
var toComma = [a, b, c];
//Variables to store the value of the numbers with commas.
var aComma;
var bComma;
var cComma;
//Array of variables with comma
var Comma = [aComma, bComma, cComma];
//declare counter variable for the loop later.
var i = 0;
//function to comma numbers
function commaSeparateNumber(val, vari){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    //Here is the problem.  Ideally, I want something here so this works, and I can plug in a different variable and value every fraction of a second into this funciton.  I could just create multiple DIFFERENT functions, but I have a large number of variables that need to be comma-ed, so I want something like this current setup that works.
    vari = val;
}
//Interval calling the function with different numbers.
setInterval(update, 1000);
function update() {
    //When the loop successfully cycles through the numbers in the array, it restarted from the first value (0).
    if(i = toComma.length - 1){
        i = 0}
    //Runs function with desired variables.
    commaSeparateNumber(toComma[i], Comma[i])
    //Increases i to loop through with the next value.
    i++
}
//Testing for me to see the number pop up in console.  They return as "undefined" everytime.
setInterval(display, 1000)
function display() {
    console.log(aComma);
    console.log(bComma);
    console.log(cComma);
}
```

Comment: Make the function return a value, then you can call it and assign the result to different variables. This is basic programming technology.

Comment: Beside your code, could you elaborate your inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: guess this is what you want... http://jsfiddle.net/8zo07j87/

Answer (score 0):

A general purpose function should return a value, not set a global variable.

```
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    //Whatever sole variable you want 
    return val;
}
```

Then you can call it and assign the result to different variables:

```
comma[i] = commaSeparateNumber(toComma[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out! I can't believe I overlooked something so simple.

Comment: Actually this solution makes me feel flat out stupid -_-

Comment: A question: You say to do:
'comma[i] = commaSeparateNumber(toComma[i]);'

What is another way to loop this indefinitely without using setIntervals as they can only utilize functions, which this cannot be in?  I can't use a While or For loop because if I run them indefinitely, they will crash.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a `for` loop. There are only 3 elements in the `comma` array.

Comment: This was just an example demonstrating my need. I actually have 10 variables that need commas.

Comment: There's no problem with a loop over 10 elements. As long as the loop isn't infinite, just use a `for` loop.

Comment: But the problem is the numbers aren't static. I am trying to make a small game to test my knowledge of JavaScript, and the number go up and down pretty quickly. Because of this, I need something to keep on updating the numbers so long as the player is on the page.

Comment: You seem to be talking about two different issues. Your first question was how to update different variables with your function, and I answered that. The second is how to do different array elements at different times, and that you seem to be doing correctly with setInterval. You just need to change the `display` function to display the variable you updated, with `console.log(comma[i])` instead of `console.log(aComma)`.